# Going down from C++ to C: alternative to std::map?

Tags: c++, c, stdmap, wdk

I am looking for minimalistic alternative for std::map<long, int>, which would go into Windows kernel driver, so it should be quite fast.. it is expected to hold a relatively small (~200 in working set) amount of keys and a large amount of inserts.

Looking for solution that can cut key search cost.

Comment: If you're feeling daring, you can implement your own hash map - if it has a very specific use, you could make it very efficient and as minimal as needed.

Comment: "which change value often." - That is, the keys are mostly frozen but there are lots of inserts with the same keys?

Comment: @delnan, yes, for single key there is about 100-200 changes per lifetime

Comment: Have you proven `std::map` is too slow?

Comment: I'd go with an AVL tree, but I'll leave for someone who can link you a such for windows to answer.

Comment: @AJG85: stl code can throw exceptions, he said he's looking to put this code in a driver so stl cannot be used (if he's sane)

Comment: @James oops glossed over that apparently. He may still be able to use a fixed container size to avoid exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Already done for you.

See the RtlXxxGenericTable and RtlXxxGenericTableAvl calls.

- [RtlInitializeElementGenericTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff552989%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- RtlDeleteElementGenericTable
- RtlEnumerateGenericTable
- RtlEnumerateGenericTableWithoutSplaying
- RtlGetElementGenericTable
- RtlInsertElementGenericTable
- RtlLookupElementGenericTable
- RtlNumberGenericTableElements
- [RtlInitializeElementGenericTableAvl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh406465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- RtlDeleteElementGenericTableAvl
- RtlEnumerateGenericTableAvl
- RtlGetElementGenericTableAvl
- RtlInitializeGenericTable
- RtlInsertElementGenericTableAvl
- RtlLookupElementGenericTableAvl
- RtlNumberGenericTableElementsAvl

Comment: It's Windows specific solution!

Comment: I don't think he cares about portability much for a `Windows kernel driver`.

Answer (score 3):

If the number of keys is *very* small, e.g. 10 or something, perhaps you can get away with just a linear search. If you take care to keep the key-space compressed in memory to maximise cache hits, it can be pretty fast and have very low overhead in terms of memory allocations and so on.

Comment: If you keep the keys in order, you can do a binary search without the need for a special data structure. Insertions may be a little expensive (but really they aren't), but lookup is fast and storage is efficient.

Comment: Insertions can be made nearly O(log(n)) if nodes are gapped, which should have minimal impact on lookup _as long as_ the tree remains at least half-full.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement `std::map` semantics in C as well. Only that it will not be `template`.

Here is the start:

```
struct KeyValuePair
{
   KeyType key;
   ValueType value;
};

struct Map
{
   KeyValuePair *list; //it can be linkedlist as well
};

//these are the interfaces which operate on map
void Insert(Map * map, KeyType key, ValueType value);
void Update(Map * map, KeyType key, ValueType value);
int Find(Map * map, KeyType key, ValueType *outValue);

//Implement Get in terms of Find
ValueType Get(Map * map, KeyType key)
{
     ValueType value;
     Find(map, key, &value);
     return value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the past, for maps with less than a few thousand objects, I've found that creating a std::vector sorted on the key value that is then searched for using a binary search is significantly faster than using a std::map.

Comment: This is not the case if you use a faster allocator for the map.  Both GCC (__gnu_cxx::pool_allocator) and MSVC (stdext::allocator_variable_size) come with allocators designed for this purpose.  I don't understand when to use which of MSVC's though.  I'll have to test sometime.

Answer (score 2):

STL map implementation is a red-black tree I believe

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B%29](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C++%29)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: +1 for trees.  if you know there's an upper limit on how many nodes you'll need, statically allocate them and have a stack of free nodes instead of doing a malloc() for every insert.

Comment: @Brian: Tree is a horrible structure for kernal modules (lots of pointers). In kernal mode you should prefer fixed size structures (or with very few moving parts). Though you can implement a balanced tree using an array.

Comment: Please explain.  In C, arrays are little more than syntactic sugar for pointers.  W/ regard to fixed-size, that's why i suggested statically allocating a pool of nodes.

Comment: @Brian: Arrays decay into pointers. That does not make them the same.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two companion arrays in C: one for keys, the other for values.  It'd help if you could encapsulate the two so users could stick to map semantics.

Comment: I would go for one array of 'struct {long Key, int value}'

Answer (score 1):

If you need a simple implementation of a dictionary in C, it's funnier to implement a dictionary in C one day... but we don't have always time to do it.

So you could try to have a look to [iniparser module one](http://ndevilla.free.fr/iniparser/), it is a little dictionary usable in a kernel and/or embedded world.